# Running scripts in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell

I have close to 50 servers to work on. Most of them are unix based servers. 
But I am working through a windows machine to access these because the client VPN is supported only in Windows. 
Problem:
I have to backup several files from these 50+ servers on a regular basis. I do that individually using Powershell pscp. But this has to be done manually for each server.
So what I need is something like a unix bash script, where I can write all the pscp commands and then run it, so it copies all the files to the desired location. 
Is this possible in Windows?. If yes, how?

Comment: The default scripting languages on Windows are batch and PowerShell (there's also VBScript, but I wouldn't recommend that for running external commands). Please go find a tutorial for either of them. SO is not a replacement for familiarizing yourself with a new language.

Comment: Does PSCP work with PowerShell?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686686/does-pscp-work-with-powershell

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Windows 10, you've got a couple of options...

**Option-1**: Microsoft released the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq) a while back. You install the WSL first. Then you can install a Linux distro of your choice. After that, you have a shell integrated with Windows. I use WSL w/Ubuntu, and I have no complaints.

**Option-2**: Enable and use [Windows 10's built in SSH support](https://www.howtogeek.com/336775/how-to-enable-and-use-windows-10s-built-in-ssh-commands/). This gives you the same (similar) ssh client you're familiar with from Unix/Linux in Windows. You can find instructions from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse). I have no used this.

**Option-3**: You can use the Posh-SSH module. This module provides the functionality of an SSH client through a native Powershell interface, and it's usable outside of Windows 10. See [this](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2016/04/using-ssh-with-powershell/) article for guidance.

A-